# Any way to get iOS system default theme colors

Tags: ios, swift, colors, themes

In my app, I have programmatically changed the colours of some widgets, e.g. `navigation bar`, `buttons`.

Now, if I want to tell my app to restore system provided colours (default) for the widgets, is that any way to achieve that since I don't want to store all the system colours somewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 5 - iOS 13+

Yes, setting the color to nil will revert back to the default colors. And this will work appropriately with Dark mode too.

Examples:

```
myButton.textColor = nil
navBar.titleTextAttributes?[.foregroundColor] = nil
navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes?[.foregroundColor] = nil
navBar.barTintColor = nil
```

where navBar is the instance of your navigation bar.

Comment: If i have a stroke with line width and color, how to set the stroke color to default colors?